# Why am I getting 'unable to create directory - Permission denied' error while using a software running as another user?

Tags: permissions, users

I'm trying to run Brave Browser from `user1` as `user2` with the `su` command:

```
su user2
/usr/bin/brave-browser
```

The config files of the browser are stored in the config folder of `user2`. Also, I edited the `su` file allowing me to `su user2` without password prompt.

Brave loads (because I allowed to run graphically in my user with `xhost +`), but configurations are not loaded properly and the log in the terminal shows a lot of errors like this:

```
(brave:4966): dconf-CRITICAL **: 20:22:13.614: unable to create directory '/run/user/1001/dconf': Permission denied.  dconf will not work properly.
```

This doesn't happen when I'm logged in as `user2` from the actual login screen (also, how can I be terminologically more accurate about these different login types? i.e. login from the shell when running as another user and login from the login screen).

Thank you

Comment: It may not seem like it, but in fact https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/434494/5132 is a related question.  As is https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/82974/5132 .

Comment: I can't vote yet so I'll comment: thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for! Some minutes ago I realized that my I'd is the one in the error shown, and I got confused because I though that su'ing user2 was sufficient to act as a login. Now things are clear.